# Reordering factor levels

Tags: r, categorical-data

I had used the `arrange()` function to order my data by two variables (`Week`, `Treatment`). Now I would like to change the order in which the `Treatment` levels are sorted, while retaining the overall grouping by `Week`. My `Treatment` column is currently sorted alphabetically and reads:

```
HQ_HI_D,
HQ_HI_E,
HQ_RI_D,
HQ_RI_E,
HQ_SI_D,
HQ_SI_E,
LQ_HI_D,
LQ_HI_E,
LQ_RI_D,
LQ_RI_E,
LQ_SI_D,
LQ_SI_E
```

And this then repeats for each week, in ascending week order. For the sake of achieving a certain arrangement of plots in a panel using `facet_wrap()`, I would like to change the order of `Treatment` within each week to:

```
HQ_HI_D,
HQ_HI_E,
LQ_HI_D,
LQ_HI_E,
HQ_SI_D,
HQ_SI_E,
LQ_SI_D,
LQ_SI_E,
HQ_RI_D,
HQ_RI_E,
LQ_RI_D,
LQ_RI_E
```

Is there a way to reorder the levels while retaining the hierarchy of the `arrange` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fct_relevel` from `forcats` ([documentation](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_relevel.html)):

```r
dat <- dat |> 
  mutate(Treatment = fct_relevel(Treatment, levels = c(
    "HQ_HI_D",
    "HQ_HI_E",
    "LQ_HI_D",
    "LQ_HI_E",
    "HQ_SI_D",
    "HQ_SI_E",
    "LQ_SI_D",
    "LQ_SI_E",
    "HQ_RI_D",
    "HQ_RI_E",
    "LQ_RI_D",
    "LQ_RI_E"
  )))
```

Then you can use this dataframe in a ggplot.

Data that you provided in the comments - and with `arrange()`:

```r
dat <- structure(list(
        Treatment = c("HQ_HI_D", "HQ_HI_E", "HQ_RI_D",  "HQ_RI_E", "HQ_SI_D", "HQ_SI_E"),
        Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L),
        Mean = c(5.64103269488891, 5.40517308877442, 5.24415513672137,  6.11270063463203, 5.47484895265563, 5.13310791453372),
        SD = c(3.48942634530154,  3.0034679069181, 2.32191693548654, 3.29315597437363, 2.73351044931912,  2.9723575474112)),
        row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") |>
    arrange(Week, Treatment)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the suggestion. When I tried it I received the following error and warning messages: ```Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Treatment = fct_relevel(Treatment, levels = c("HQ_HI_D", "HQ_HI_E", "LQ_HI_D", ...`.
Caused by error:
! attempt to apply non-function
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Problem while computing `Treatment = fct_relevel(Treatment, levels = c("HQ_HI_D", "HQ_HI_E", "LQ_HI_D", ...`.
ℹ Outer names are only allowed for unnamed scalar atomic inputs```

Comment: Have you called `library(forcats)` beforehand?

Comment: Yes I installed and loaded library(forcats)

Comment: Please edit your question to add your data in code form - you can do it by copying the output of `dput(head(datasetname))` or by creating fake data with `data.frame()`. This way I’ll be able to test it

Comment: ah okay, thank you! ```structure(list(Treatment = c("HQ_HI_D", "HQ_HI_E", "HQ_RI_D", 
"HQ_RI_E", "HQ_SI_D", "HQ_SI_E"), Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Mean = c(5.64103269488891, 5.40517308877442, 5.24415513672137, 
6.11270063463203, 5.47484895265563, 5.13310791453372), SD = c(3.48942634530154, 
3.0034679069181, 2.32191693548654, 3.29315597437363, 2.73351044931912, 
2.9723575474112)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: Thanks. I originally forgot to close a bracket in my code. I've updated it now and I get no error - just a warning, but the code works. Have a look.